# Deploy PyQt5 application on different Linux machine

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt, cx-freeze, pyqt5

I'm struggling with this problem since a week now so I guess it's time to ask for some help. Long story short: I'm building an application using Python 3.4 and PyQt5 and I'm using cx_Freeze to create a standalone executable of my application. While on Windows and Mac OS everything goes fine I encountered this problem while executing my frozen application on a Ubuntu operating system on which Qt5 is not installed:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, offscreen, xcb.
```

The application runs fine on the machine I'm using to build the frozen package (where Qt5 is installed).

I have googled a bit and it seems that this problem is quite common. I tried everything I could find in the following links:

- ["Failed to load platform plugin "xcb" " while launching qt5 app on linux without qt installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106315/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without)
- [(Qt 5.4.1) This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405689/qt-5-4-1-this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-th)

In the frozen application I do have the platforms directory in which there is `libqxcb.so`. Just for consistency I'm posting the output of the `ldd libqxcb.so` which is the same on both the machines where Qt5 is installed, and the other one I'm using for testing where I only have a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install (no Qt5):

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff563a3000)
libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007feddfeee000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007feddfcec000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007feddfadc000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007feddf8d4000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007feddf6b8000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007feddf499000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007feddf25d000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007feddefba000)
libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007fedded3b000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007feddeb39000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fedde931000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fedde629000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fedde41f000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fedde20d000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007feddded8000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007feddd88b000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007feddd1e5000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007feddcf53000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007feddcd35000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007feddca31000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007feddc72b000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007feddc515000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007feddc150000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fede02f4000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007feddbf4b000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007feddbd47000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007feddbb41000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007feddb917000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007feddb6fe000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007feddb4d8000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007feddb293000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007feddb055000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007feddae00000)
libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52 (0x00007fedda9f9000)
libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00007fedda680000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007fedda456000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fedda253000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fedda04d000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fedd9e36000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007fedd9c31000)
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007fedd9a2e000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007fedd982b000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007fedd9625000)
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007fedd9423000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fedd921d000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fedd9011000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fedd8df5000)
libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0x00007fedd7588000)
```

The same applies to `ldd Eddy` (where Eddy is the application executable name):

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc812e000)
libpython3.4m.so.1.0 => /home/daniele/Desktop/eddy/build/Eddy-0.4-gpl-linux64/./libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (0x00007fab72345000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fab72127000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fab71d62000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fab71b38000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fab7191f000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fab7171b000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fab71518000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fab71212000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fab7297a000)
```

On the machine where I'm creating the frozen application I tried both Qt5 compiled from source and Qt5 installed using the offline installer. I used **SIP 4.17** and **PyQt5 5.5.1** compiled from sources and **cx_Freeze 3.4.3**.

Any advice?

**EDIT1**: I already tried moving libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 (along with libQt5QCore.so.5, etc..) into my build directory but it didn't help.

Comment: Try finding `libQt5XcbQpa.so.5` (the one it says is not found) and copying it into the build directory.

Comment: Was the first thing I tried (forgot to mention it) but it didn't help. It's also missing on my development machine but there the application stats just fine, so I guess the problem is somewhere else :(

Comment: mostly looks like you need 32bit version for some modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the library files to the build directory is not enough for Linux targets. Make sure the directory is in your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

These instructions taken from the QT Deployment [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html) might help:

> Unless told otherwise, the dynamic linker doesn't search the directory
>   where your application resides. There are many ways to solve this:
>
> - You can install the Qt libraries in one of the system library paths
>     (e.g. /usr/lib on most systems).
> - You can pass a predetermined path to the -rpath command-line option when linking the application. This will tell the dynamic linker to look in this > directory when starting your application.
> - You can write a startup script for your application,
>     where you modify the dynamic linker configuration (e.g., adding your
>     application's directory to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
>
> **Note:** If your application will be running with "Set user ID on
>   execution," and if it will be owned by root, then LD_LIBRARY_PATH will
>   be ignored on some platforms. In this case, use of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH approach is not an option).

Comment: Thanks you. Even though I figured it out before reading your answer, you are correct. I'll give you the bounty for the effort though :).