# This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

this [exist answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405689/qt-5-4-1-this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-th) can not fix my question

In qt [official example](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/tree/5.5/examples/widgets/desktop/systray), I use following CMakeLists.txt

```
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qtbase)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_library(xcb NAMES qxcb PATHS /media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qtbase/plugins/platforms)
add_executable(systray main.cpp window.cpp systray.qrc)
target_link_libraries(systray Qt5::Widgets ${xcb})
```

and I get

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
```

How to add "xcb" plugin to cmake?

**update**

I'm sure `find_library(xcb` find the lib "/media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so".

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu or Debian, the xcb plugin is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so`. It's installed by the `libqt5gui5` package, so it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

when I `ldd /media/roroco/disk750/Downloads/qtbase/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so`, there are some deps show "not found", so I guess the reason it's that

the temp solution what i find is add

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${qt_rt}/lib
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=${qt_rt}/plugins
export QT_QPA_FONTDIR=${qt_rt}/lib/fonts
```

to ~/.bashrc and source ~/.bashrc, reopen editor and try again.

but here is question, when i use `set(ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} path/to/qtbase/lib)` in CMakeLists.txt instead of `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:path/to/qtbase/lib` in ~/.bashrc, it doesn't work, it still raise error, if someone know the reason, please create new answer for this question, I think change env in cmake is better way

Comment: Don't post additional info as an answer. Better edit or comment on the question message.