# Running qtcreator 4.0.1 on a lxc-container

Tags: qt-creator, lxc, xcb

Using [this link](http://nik90.com/fiddling-around-with-lxc-containers/) I created a container and after getting some packages, I want to start a qtcreator 4.0.1 on it. I use a ssh connection to connect to the container. After launching qtcreator I get an error such as this:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I installed all prerequisites packages as listed [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-requirements.html) but still the problem is remained. 
I must mention that I am using a privileged container in opposite of the [link](http://nik90.com/fiddling-around-with-lxc-containers/).

`xcb` listed as available plug-ins but it does not run. Is there any suggestion to get around this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29409172/2335245) has the main solution. In my case I find the `libqxcb.so` in path `/path_to_qt/plugins/platforms/` and after running `ldd` command on it I found that it has not one of its dependency `libEGL.so` after install this package using `sudo apt install libegl-mesa0-dev` I could run qtcreator.