# not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" even it exists

Tags: qt, platform

I downloaded one of application from [a link here] (https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/gnishida/photo/).

I want to create 3D model from an image. But it is giving an error about Qt platform plugin windows.

I downloaded 6 GB of application from the site, and tried to run it, first it gives an error on some missing CUDA libraries, for which i downloaded old CUDA framework 7.0 (1 GB) and taken from there. But when i tried again to run the tool again, It gives "Missing platform plugin in windows". I tried to download qt creator, then i copied plugins/platforms folder into application folder, but still giving the same error.

**Edit** Following are the contents of 6 GB application file.
Following are the contents of that 5.7 GB download.

```
cga (Folder) (contains some xml files of doors, windows etc.)
data (folder)(contains ctr, xml and jpg files)
hatching (folder) (contains some images files)
Material (folder) (contains some images files)
models (folder) (contains subfolders, having files end with .prototxt and caffemodel)
shaders (folder) (contains .glsl files)
textures (folder) (contain some image files)
boost_chrono-vc120-mt-1_58.dll
boost_system-vc120-mt-1_58.dll
boost_thread-vc120-mt-1_58.dll
CGAL_Core-vc120-mt-4.13.dll
CGAL_ImageIO-vc120-mt-4.13.dll
CGAL-vc120-mt-4.13.dll
cublas64_70.dll (i added this from CUDA 7.0)
cudart64_70.dll (i added this from CUDA 7.0)
curand64_70.dll (i added this from CUDA 7.0)
glew32.dll
hdf5_hl.dll
hdf5_hl_cpp.dll
hdf5_hl_f90cstub.dll
hdf5_hl_fortran.dll
hdf5_tools.dll
libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
libgflags.dll
libgfortran-3.dll
libglog.dll
libgmp-10.dll
libmpfr-4.dll
libopenblas.dll
libquadmath-0.dll
opencv_world300.dll
PhotoTo3D.exe (Which i was trying to run)
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5OpenGL.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
Qt5Xml.dll
szip.dll
zlib.dll
```

I tried adding 'plugins/platforms' folders and its libraries directly and also tried to create qt.conf to make application work, i also tried to add environment variables. These are all suggestions from different platforms. None of them worked for me.

I even tried it on different laptop, i thought it is because of hardware issue, but issue remain the same.

I even tried to fix it setting environmental variables but issue remained the same.

The tool itself opened, crashed and remove within a second.
So I used CMD to navigate to path and tried.

```
CD C:\Users\Muhammad Wajeeh\Desktop\Research On Photos
"PhotoTo3D.exe"
```

I expected an application whose interface may be created due to Qt libraries, which may take image as input, and create 3D building but it is not possible.
You can see it [at youtube](https://youtu.be/zPvCnorXERQ)

Comment: Here is the error image [output.](https://ibb.co/ydDbJXN)
platform plugin is available but not picked by the program.

Comment: Yes, and author didn't mentioned in his paper, or work, even i commented on his video. I tried downloading and installing Qt creator 3.5 and Qt creator 4.1 to get the plugins/platforms folder, didn't work for me. Does newer version will work like 5.13 if i download? may be some functions in application got obsolete or not present in newer versions? 

Yes it is a bit programming related as on site from where i downloaded this file, it was mentioned as source code.

Comment: Wait a minute, I could have been correct in the first place. Did you rebuild the code? Or are you trying to run executables that are in the 5.7 GB download? If there are exeutables in the download you need to rebuild or use the same version of the Qt framework.

Comment: Yes i added all contents, the author made a link with code, but it contains execute able file (PhotoTo3D.exe), dll libraries, and images.

Comment: You have to determine what version of Qt these files are from. Its not 5.13

Comment: `vc120` is extremely important. This means the code was compiled with Visual Studio 2013 and you need VS2013 binaries for `Qt`. You can't mix compiler versions. Any different version of Visual Studio (or any other compiler's binaries) will be incompatible.

Comment: I updated structure of file in my question, please check it and let me know.

Comment: I checked. This is all the advice I can give. You need to figure out what `Qt` binary download you need for Visual Studio 2013. Looking at the other files this is at least 1 maybe 2 years old. I would look there.

Comment: Ok, I try, Thank You. I have installed visual studio 2012, i will remove it and install VS-2013. Btw i already installed .NET framework 4.8 and visual c++ runtime 2017. Will these help or do i need to install visual studio 2013? Won't it work without installing VS-2013?

Comment: ***Btw i already installed .NET framework 4.8 and visual c++ runtime 2017.*** None of that will help.

Comment: ***Won't it work without installing VS-2013?*** You need `Qt` that was compiled with Visual Studio 2013 and the same version as they are using. It could be `5.9` or even older. I am not sure.

Comment: Boost 1.58 was released in 2015: https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_58_0.html

Comment: You may need this version of `Qt` https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.5/5.5.1/ and specifically this file: `qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64-5.5.1.exe`

Comment: Thank You For Your Time Mate. I try it, i will consult with author too, if he may help. I will add answer in steps if i found solution of my question.

Comment: You can try to set `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` to `...\plugins`, or set `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` to debug what's going wrong (see something similar for Linux [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40991619/7231208)).

Answer (score 0):

You just need the platforms directory, with the right Qt dlls in it.

You should have a directory structure as follows:

[image]

**Before** organizing the directory as above, I got the error:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "windows". Reinstalling the application may fix
>   this problem.

(note that the above dlls are the debug ones - they end with *-d.dll* - just pick the ones you need instead).