# While starting the emulator I'm getting Emulator Error?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

While starting the emulator I'm getting the following error.
If anyone can solve the problem please share with me.

```
Emulator: Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin 
          could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.  
Emulator: ((null):0, (null))
Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 
          (0xC0000409)
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you actually try reinstalling the application as it says in the error output?
Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405689/qt-5-4-1-this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-th/29409172) are some answers that could help you with your problem